# Linker Tools Error while configured and build wxWidgets Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, linker, wxwidgets, linker-errors

Not able to configure wxwidgets in Visual Studio 2017.

Followed these steps.

- From wxwidgets website, downloaded Source Code 'Windows 7Z' file, Version 3.1.3.
- Run the `wx_vc15.sln` from `build` ->`msw` in Visual Studio 2017.
- Build the `Debub`, `DLL Debug`, `DLL Release`, `Relese` successfully with Platform `x86`.

In `Microsoft Visual Studio 17 V15.9.20`, created an empty project. Added a [simple](http://zetcode.com/gui/wxwidgets/firstprograms/) wxWidgets program.

In `project properties` made the below changes
 - In `All Configurations` with Platform `Win32`, Set the `Configuration Properties` -> `Character Set` to `Use Unicode Character Set`

- `C/C++` -> `Additional Include Directories` -> `$(WXWIN)\include\msvc;$(WXWIN)\include;`
- `C/C++` -> `Preprocessor` -> `Preprocessor Defenitions` -> `__WXMSW__;WXUSINGDLL;_DEBUG`
- `Linker` -> `Additional Library Directories` -> `$(WXWIN)\lib\vc_dll`

Made these changes in `Environment Variables`

- In `User variables`

  - Add a new variable `WXWIN` and set its value to  `C:\Users\varun\Desktop\workspace\wxWidgets-3.1.3`.
  - Path -> `C:\Users\varun\Desktop\workspace\wxWidgets-3.1.3\lib\vc_dll`.

In project properties `Release` Configurations,  made these changes
`C/C++` -> `Preprocessor` -> `Preprocessor Defenitions` -> `__WXMSW__;WXUSINGDLL;NDEBUG;`

There is no code error but `Linker Tools Error`

```
Error (active)  E1097   unknown attribute "no_init_all" WxWidgets_Application_5 C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\um\winnt.h  

Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ) WxWidgets_Application_3 C:\Users\varun\Desktop\workspace\visual_studio_projects_2017\WxWidgets_Application_3\WxWidgets_Application_3\MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)

Error LNK1120 1 unresolved externals WxWidgets_Application_3 C:\Users\varun\Desktop\workspace\visual_studio_projects_2017\WxWidgets_Application_3\Debug\WxWidgets_Application_3.exe
```

What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error you show is not an error at all but just some IntelliSense noise, see this [bug report](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/387702/vs-2017-1592-reports-unknown-attribute-no-init-all.html). The real error is not being able to find `_main` which seems to indicate that you're building a console application (see `Properties\Linker\System\SubSystem` option), so it should be fixed by just making it a Windows application instead.

Also, while I don't see anything really wrong with your setup, I would still recommend using the [official instructions](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/blob/v3.1.3/docs/msw/install.md) instead. Notably in your case it should be as simple as:

> If you use MSVS 2010 or later IDE for building your project, simply add `wxwidgets.props` property sheet to (all) your project(s) using wxWidgets. You don't need to do anything else.

Comment: **(see Properties\Linker\System\SubSystem option), so it should be fixed by just making it a Windows application instead.** This solved the issues. Thanks :)